# Access custom properties about unity game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, inheritance, gameobject

I've searched for the answer to this for at least an hour now, and everything gets me more confused. Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a Tray that accepts a Cube. Depending on the orientation of the Cube, the Tray will relay one of six pieces of information (one for each side).

This only works if the Cube is placed in the Tray.

I have a script running on the Tray that is trying to figure out if the Cube is placed close enough to register the information.

The Cube has the information itself. How do I get the Tray to tell me the Cube's personal information?

My initial idea was to inherit Cube from GameObject. But I can't inherit from a sealed class, etc.

Any insight would be wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us come pieces of code that you already have written? Why would you want to have cube inherit from GameObject?

Comment: I think I got it. You can make a script, and then access its gameObject via .gameObject.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by

> personal information

Every [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) inherits from the [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) class which has some properties e.g.

- [`gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html), a reference to the `GameObject` this component is attached to.
- [`transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) a reference to the `Transform` component on the same `GameObject` holding information about position and orientation.
- [`name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html) the `GameObject`'s name

if you rather mean some values of the `Cube` script itself you should implement some getter properties like

```
private int someInt;
private string someString;

public int SomeInt
{
    get { return someInt; }
}

// often also written like
public string SomeString => someString;
```

---

For distances you can use [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) like e.g.

```
if(Vector3.Distance(cubeObject.transform.position, trayObject.transform.position) <= someThresholdvalue)
{
    // ...
}
```